# How to include a shared library with SConstruct?

Tags: shared-libraries, scons, dynamic-linking

I have built a shared library from a part of the Mobile Robot Programming Toolkit ( [MRPT-Homepage](http://www.mrpt.org) ). Now I am wondering how to include this in my SConstruct build script? I have the headerfiles for the lib and the .so.

I googled around for some time, but I was not able to figure out a solution and hence would be very happy if someone can point me to a resource that may help or tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section from the scons user manual on [Linking with Libraries](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/x667.html) might be helpful. You just need to set `LIBS` to the list of libraries you want to link against and `LIBPATH` to the path to the library. If you're linking against a library named `libmrpt.so`, use `LIBS = ['mrpt']`.

Depending on whether this is a common library to link with, or just used once, you can set `LIBS` and `LIBPATH` in your environment (1), or for a single target (2):

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH = ['path/to/headers'],
                  LIBS = ['mrpt'], LIBPATH = ['path/to/lib'])     # (1)
...
myprog = env.Program('my_program', [...sources...], 
                     LIBS = ['mrpt'], LIBPATH = ['path/to/lib'])  # (2)
```